# Position of the IconButton in AppBar In React-JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 IconButton inside a Toolbar and I want to make one of them be on the right side and another one on the left side but both are on the right side. this is my code

```
<AppBar
    position="fixed"
    >
    <Toolbar>
    <IconButton onClick={this.drawerClickHandel}> #======> #1
        <MenuIcon style={{ marginLeft: 'auto', color:'#e0e0e0'}}/>
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton style={{flex: 'auto'}}> #======> #2
        <MenuIcon style={{ marginRight: 'auto', color:'#e0e0e0'}}/>
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton style={{flex: 'auto'}}> #======> #3
        <MenuIcon style={{ marginRight: 'auto', color:'#e0e0e0'}}/>
    </IconButton>
    </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

I want the Number 1 on the right side and number 2 and 3 on left side of the Toolbar

Comment: Use the ``Grid`` component for this

Comment: @Tracer69 you mean Instead of Toolbar I use Grid?

Answer (score 0):

I Find My Answer I should use `<Div` around of my iconButton 2 and 3 like this

```
<AppBar
position="fixed"
>
<Toolbar>
<IconButton onClick={this.drawerClickHandel}> #======> #1
    <MenuIcon style={{ marginLeft: 'auto', color:'#e0e0e0'}}/>
</IconButton>
<Div ClassName="MyDiv">
    <IconButton style={{flex: 'auto'}}> #======> #2
        <MenuIcon style={{ marginRight: 'auto', color:'#e0e0e0'}}/>
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton style={{flex: 'auto'}}> #======> #3
        <MenuIcon style={{ marginRight: 'auto', color:'#e0e0e0'}}/>
    </IconButton>
</Div>
</Toolbar>
```

And for css file

```
.MyDiv{
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```